# R won't recognize column names as an object

Tags: r

I'm trying to build a histogram of residual values, however the first step I'm taking to do that is to run a linear model. R will not recognize the column name as an object.

The first three lines of code run fine. The second two give me an error saying the object area_ha cant be found, however, it is one of eight column titles in my data. Any advice on creating a linear model and a histogram to graph residuals would also be very helpful.

```
dat<-read.csv("/Users/sara/Desktop/birdsinforest.csv", header=TRUE)
linearmodel=lm(abundance ~ area_ha, data = dat)
summary(linearmodel)
area_ha$abundance_predicted = predict(linearmodel)
area_ha$residual = area_ha$abundance - area_ha$abundance_predicted
```

This is the error I get after running the last two lines of code:

Error in area_ha$abundance_predicted = predict(linearmodel) : 
  object 'area_ha' not found

Comment: `area_ha` is one of your columns so you cannot subset it with `$`.  Did you want `dat$abundance_predicted` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
dat<-read.csv("/Users/sara/Desktop/birdsinforest.csv", header=TRUE)
linearmodel=lm(abundance ~ area_ha, data = dat)
summary(linearmodel)
area_ha$abundance_predicted = predict(linearmodel)
area_ha$residual = area_ha$abundance - area_ha$abundance_predicted
```

In the above code, `area_ha` seems like a variable (column name) and not `data.frame` since you're using it to fit a linear model. You should try the last two lines of code as below:

```
dat$abundance_predicted <- predict(linearmodel)
dat$residual <- dat$abundance - dat$abundance_predicted
```